# Cake Task output log to file

Tags: cakebuild

I have a set of Tasks inside a `build.cake` file and I would like to capture the log output from the console into a log file. I know it's possible to use the `OnError()` function to output errors to file but I would like to output everything to a log file, not just errors.
Below is an example of the `build.cake` file.

```
#load "SomeTask.cake"
#load "SomeOtherTask.cake"

var target = Argument("target", "Default");

var someTask = Task("SomeTask")
.Does(() =>
{
     SomeMethodInsideSomeTask();
});

var someOtherTask = Task("SomeOtherTask")
.Does(() => 
{
    SomeOtherMethodInsideSomeOtherTask();
});

Task("Default")
.IsDependentOn(someTask)
.IsDependentOn(someOtherTask);

RunTarget(target);
```

N.B. The Tasks are not running any sort of `MSBuild` commands so it's not possible to use [MSBuildFileLogger](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.MSBuild/MSBuildFileLogger/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about pipe the stdout to a file i.e.

> ./build.ps1 > log.txt

Comment: I mistakenly thought it was only possible too pipe the stdout using powershell. I was able to get the output to file using the following command `cake.exe build.cake -Verbosity=diagnostic > Build.log`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) ?
It reads standard input and writes it to both standard output and one or more files